# Execute sql statements wrapped in a clob with dbms_sql.parse

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I want to execute some sql statements stored in a clob in the database.
I want to make use of dbms_sql.parse with a clob as input parameter.

The code I tried as a testcase on a 11.2 Oracle database:

Making the table for the inserts:

```
create table table1 (t1 number(8), t2 varchar2(1), t3 varchar2(1));
```

The statement that fails:

```
DECLARE
  cursor makeclob is
   select 'insert into table1 (t1,t2,t3) values ('||rownum||', ''X'',''I'');' stat
   from dual
   connect by level < 10000;

  testcl clob;
  opencu integer;
  err integer;
BEGIN
  for rec in makeclob loop
    testcl := testcl || rec.stat || '\n';
  end loop;
  testcl := testcl || 'commit;'|| '\n';
  opencu := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

  dbms_sql.parse(opencu,testcl,dbms_sql.native);

  err := dbms_sql.execute(opencu);
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(opencu);
END;
```

This statement failed with the following error:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1250
ORA-06512: at line 17
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your parsed statements between

> BEGIN

and

> END

Also use chr(13) instead of '\n'.

I ajusted your code a little bit, so take a look at this:

```
DECLARE
  cursor makeclob is
   select 'insert into table1 (t1,t2,t3) values ('||rownum||', ''X'',''I'');' stat
   from dual
   connect by level < 10000;

  testcl clob;
  opencu integer;
  err integer;
BEGIN
  testcl := 'BEGIN'||chr(13);
  for rec in makeclob loop
    testcl := testcl || rec.stat ||chr(13);
  end loop;
  testcl := testcl || 'commit;'||chr(13);
  testcl := testcl || 'END;';
  opencu := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

  dbms_sql.parse(opencu,testcl,dbms_sql.native);

  err := dbms_sql.execute(opencu);
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(opencu);
END;
```